# On centered menu, left icon is missing left border

Tags: semantic-ui

When I center my menu items using `justify-content: center` the left border of the left icon disappears. (View issue on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markjackson02/fwngctpo/6/))

My workaround is to manually assign a border using `.add-left-border`. However I'm not sure why this is required. Anybody know what's going on here?

```css
#header-menu {
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Why do I have to add this for border to show up? */
.add-left-border {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(34,36,38,.15);
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css"/>

<div class="ui icon menu" id="header-menu">
  <a class="item add-left-border">
    <i class="code branch icon "></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="github icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="envelope icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the buttons have a left border as they all apply borders to their right side (see below), while the first button depends on the menu's border to provide its visual boundary.

```css
.ui.menu .item::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: rgba(34,36,38,.1);
}
```

You will always need to use a bespoke solution as the framework doesn't appear to provide a centered menu. For purposes of consistency and cleaner HTML, you can achieve it with only CSS modifications:

```css
#header-menu {
    justify-content: center;
}

#header-menu .item:first-child::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: rgba(34,36,38,.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css"/>
<div class="ui icon menu" id="header-menu">
  <a class="item">
    <i class="code branch icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="github icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    <i class="envelope icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```